# NameError: name 'framechange' is not defined

Tags: tkinter, frame, tk-toolkit, nameerror

I'm trying to make a basic password storage program in python and am unsure how to call the "framechange" function when the login button is clicked and get the error "NameError: name 'framechange' is not defined"

`class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    entry = "password"
    def framechange(get):
        if entry.get() == "password":
            controller.show_frame("PageOne")
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10, padx=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Login",command = lambda: framechange)
        button1.pack()`

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

`framechange` is not a method of the class without`(self)` as the first arg.

```
def framechange(self, get)
```

Also, are you sure you need `lambda`?  You should just be able to pass the framechange function itself, lambda is for defining a fcn on the fly.

Comment: my revised code is 
    `entry = "password"
    def framechange(self, get):
        if self.entry.get() == "password":
            controller.show_frame("PageOne")`

`button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Login",command = self.framechange)`

I now get the error message TypeError: framechange() missing 1 required positional argument: 'get'

Comment: Well, if framechange takes an argument (I don't think it should, since you never use it), then you have to call the function and pass in an argument.  From your snippet, "get" is never used in framechange.  You use entry.get, but that's different.  Try just removing get as an argument, but keep self.  IE def framechange(self)

Comment: You'll also need to refer to entry as self.entry or it's going to complain